# Exclude specific dates from date range - Python

Tags: python, arrays, date, range, delta

I tried to exclude specific dates from a range of date and not getting valid output and below is the code. Could you please help to fix it.

```
from datetime import timedelta, date

sdate = date(2020, 7, 1)
edate = date(2020, 7, 7)
delta = edate - sdate

toRemoveDate = [date(2020, 7, 6), date(2020, 7, 2)]

for i in range(delta.days + 1):
    day = sdate + timedelta(days=i)
    print(day)

    for j in range(len(toRemoveDate)):
        if day != toRemoveDate[j]:
            print(day)
```

Thanks,
Anand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
from datetime import timedelta, date

sdate = date(2020, 7, 1)
edate = date(2020, 7, 7)
delta = edate - sdate

toRemoveDate = [date(2020, 7, 6), date(2020, 7, 2)]

for i in range(delta.days + 1):
    day = sdate + timedelta(days=i)
    if day not in toRemoveDate: # <-- check if day not in list
        print(day)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try .drop()

```
from datetime import timedelta, date
import pandas as pd

sdate = date(2020, 7, 1)
edate = date(2020, 7, 7)
range = pd.date_range(start=str(sdate), end=str(edate))
toRemoveDate = [date(2020, 7, 6), date(2020, 7, 2)] 
days = range.drop(toRemoveDate)
print(days)
```